# Php executing a bash script with at command

Tags: php, shell, yii2, scheduled-tasks

Hello I'am trying to execute a shell command in my php script but it is not working.
My php script :

```
           //I save the Order 
            $holdedOrder->save();
            $id = $holdedOrder->id;
            $old_path = getcwd();
            chdir(__DIR__.'/../');
            $scriptFile = 'anacron_job_unhold_order.sh';
            $bool = file_exists($scriptFile);
            //$bool is true !

            //this command works in shell but not in here do not know why
            $s = shell_exec("echo \"/usr/bin/bash $scriptFile $id\" | /usr/bin/at now +$when");
            chdir($old_path);
            return [$s,$bool];
```

$when has a valid value `4 hours` or `4 days` ...
The command will be :

```
echo bash anacron_job_unhold_order.sh 29 | at now +1 minutes
```

the output is null. Trying it with `exec()` is returning 127 code

Edit : 
I removed www-data from /etc/at.deny and still the same problem

Comment: Why `echo bash`? use `exec(/usr/bin/bash $scriptFile..., $output); var_dump($output)` to further debug!

Comment: exit code `127` says the command is not found ;)

Comment: piping bash with the at command will execute the script immediately and will not consider the  at command but when doing echo /bin/bash  script .. will execute the script on the specific time

Comment: Anyy help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `shell_exec("echo \"/usr/bin/bash $scriptFile $id\" | /usr/bin/at now +$when");` is probably causing the issue, you should take a closer look on [how `at` works](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uat.htm).

The command should be something like

```
at [options] [job...]
```

To give a job to `at` from the command instead of STDIN, use [`heredoc syntax`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80362/what-does-mean)

```sh
at now + 1 minute <<< 'touch /tmp/test'
```

So the PHP code should be something like;

```php
$s = shell_exec("/usr/bin/at now + {$when} <<< '/usr/bin/bash {$scriptFile} {$id}'");
exec($s, $output, $return_var);
```

Comment: @AhmedJaouadi It's probably not installed, try with `sudo apt-get install at` or try with the package manager your OS uses.